# variable contains multiple object how to return it into an object of multiple object

Tags: adonis.js

i have a code here that query the database and return a variable that contains rows of records

```
  var certificateInfo = await Certification.all({'user_id': this.user_id})
```

it return `[{object},{object},{object}]`

how to return the data into

```
{object}, {object}, {object}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a loop over `certificateInfo` object or destructuring assignment:

```
[obj1, obj2, obj3] = certificateInfo
```

Hope I help.